# Which file is binary file type - Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, binary

I have to make an `API` call and  fetch the `json` data in binary file type. For this I am using below code. For file output, I have referenced this 2 post: [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393092/compress-the-data-inside-my-json-file-to-binary) and [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417814/python-basics-request-data-from-api-and-write-to-a-file). My question is which of the below code contains JSON data in binary format ? I know mode 'wb' is writes data in binary format, but not sure if both the files are in binary format? Is there a way to verify which file is in Binary format ?

I am new to `Python` and `API` calling so help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Python**

```
  import requests
    
    url = "https://covid-api.com/api/regions?iso=chn"
    
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

### Using Pickle module

```
 with open("file.pkl","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(response.content, f)
```

### Using JSON module

```
import json

with open("file.json","wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `requests` response `.json()` method - whether that is binary is probably irrelevant as it will briefly be a native Python dict (which will almost-certainly be stuffed with utf-8 strings)

```py
import json
import requests
r = requests.get(...)
r.raise_for_status()  # check if request succeeded
j = r.json()
with open(path_destination, "w") as fh:
    json.dump(j)
```

Comment: for path_destination. Should I specify file name as file.json or just file path ? I tried putting my current working directory path and it throw me an error saying "[Errno 13] Permission denied: "

Comment: `open()` is expecting the path for the file, like `file.json`, though you can select a path like `path/file.json`! `os.getcwd()` can get the current directory if the interpreter may be running from an unexpected path